# Why DBMS_Scheduler job failed?

Tags: oracle, dbms-scheduler

I have written one procedure and one job.
From job I am running procedure. Following is the script for creating job

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job  (job_name  => 'IBPROD2.RUN_FETCH_ACCT_ALERTS',
job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
job_action      => 'FETCH_ACCT_ALERTS',
start_date      => sysdate,
repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=2;',
enabled         => TRUE,
auto_drop       => FALSE
);
```

After creating job I am running following command to get job details for owner IBPROD2 where I can see failure_count column value as 1 for RUN_FETCH_ACCT_ALERTS job.
There is no problem in procedure FETCH_ACCT_ALERTS when I run it manually.

Can anyone help me in why the job is failing? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

Query the [ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1140.htm#i1587156) view (or perhaps the DBA equivalent).

```
select *
from all_scheduler_job_run_details
where job_name = 'IBPROD2.RUN_FETCH_ACCT_ALERTS'
```

You'll be particularly interested in the `error#` which will give you an Oracle error number you can look up.  Also, the `additional_info` column might have some, er, additional info.

---

The error code means [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e24280.htm#sthref6566):

> ORA-28179: client user name not provided by proxy
>       Cause: No user name was provided by the proxy user for the client user.
>       Action: Either specify a client database user name, a distinguished name or an X.509 certificate.

So it's something to do with your security set up.  Authentication is failing for reason.  As I lack a detailed knowledge of your architecture (and I'm not a security specialist) I'm not in a position to help you.

> Because I have already created many jobs to run different procedures
>   with same owner. All are running successfully.

So in what way does *this procedure* differ from all the others?

Comment: Thanks for reply. The error code is ORA-28179: client user name not provided by proxy. But I don't know how to resolve it. Do you have any idea? Because I have already created many jobs to run different procedures with same owner. All are running successfully.